# Secure Certificate Problem

Tags: security, iis

I recently installed a secure certificate for a web site I help maintain. When I'm at work and on the network where the webs server is I can navigate to secure pages (https) fine. When I try to access the same pages from outside the network (like from home) I get an error. Here is an example page from my web site: https://www.acpe.org/MyACPE/Activity/MyActivity.aspx

I assumed it might be our barracuda firewall but we completely turned it off and the problem persisted. I checked the certificate [here at Verisign](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=certchecker) and it says it's fine:

I'm at a loss. I'd appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us what error you are getting... ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.I'm not getting a numbered error code back (like 404, 100, ...). The message I get back varies from browser to browser. In IE7 I get this: "There is a problem with this website's security certificate. This organization's certificate has been revoked.
 ..."

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped with this problem. I greatly appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verisign's [OCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocsp) responder says that your certificate has been revoked.

It's likely that some environments you are using for testing don't have OCSP enabled. You can test this by disabling OCSP checks in a browser that currently fails. It should start working after that.

If your certificate is revoked, you should get another.

---

Verisign has issued several certificates for www.acpe.org. The one that is still valid has the serial number `27583686efafc6484ac19d7ce82be271`. The one that `www.acpe.org` is currently configured to use is revoked, and has a serial number of `21ee7e042a53142a9f5075fc2dbff37a`. I haven't been able to get OpenSSL's `ocsp` tool to work, so I can't see the "reason" code being given, but judging from the info there, a replacement was requested on February 10 by the certificate owner. Make sure that you correctly installed the *new* certificate.

You can see this status information through Verisign's certificate [repository tool](https://securitycenter.verisign.com/celp/enroll/outsideSearch?application_locale=VRSN_US&originator=VeriSign:CELP) by entering the common name "www.acpe.org".

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Could you point me to Verisign's OCSP responder? I can't locate it at verisign.com. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, Erickson! Somehow we just installed the wrong certificate and in trying to debug this problem I overlooked the obvious. Stupid stupid stupid. Thank you!!!

Comment: My son, Leif, is due to be born in May. Perhaps I can persuade my wife to have his middle name be Erickson in honor of you, not the explorer.

Comment: Hehe! Thanks! Accepting my answer is honor enough for me. Besides, doesn't "Magnus" have a nicer, Nordic ring?

Comment: Magnus is a nice choice. On a side note, in college I made a deal with a professor that I would name my daughter 'Ruby' in honor of his favorite language if he gave me a passing grade on a particularly hard test. He passed me and I did name her Ruby. He doesn't have to know it's a family name.

Answer (score 2):

It appears the cert expired in 2004.  This is the information I get using Netscape 4.5.1:

This Certificate belongs to:
  Class 3 Public Primary Certification
  Authority
  VeriSign, Inc.
  US

```
                           This Certificate was issued by:
                             Class 3 Public Primary Certification
                             Authority
                             VeriSign, Inc.
                             US
```

Serial Number: 00:E4:9E:FD:F3:3A:E8:0E:CF:A5:11:3E:19:A4:24:02:32
This Certificate is valid from Sun Jan 28, 1996 to Wed Jan 07, 2004
Certificate Fingerprint:
  78:2A:02:DF:DB:2E:14:D5:A7:5F:0A:DF:B6:8E:9C:5

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see what you're saying but this was working until earlier this month. This is very interesting. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: The certificate I receive has a serial number of 21:EE:7E:04:2A:53:14:2A:9F:50:75:FC:2D:BF:F3:7A. It's an RSA certificate that expires in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the certificate was revoked. Are you sure you installed a valid certificate?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Really at this point I'm not sure the certificate was installed properly. Verisign says is was when I use this tool: https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=certchecker

Comment: It's likely that this certificate checker does not perform revocation checks.